# How can you retrieve a date field in Apollo Client from a query as a Date and not a string?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using the following graphql:

```
scalar Date

type MyModel {
  id: ID!
  date: Date!
}

query MyModels {
  myModels {
    id
    date
  }
}

type Query {
  myModel: [MyModel!]
}
```

and resolvers:

```
import { DateTimeResolver } from 'graphql-scalars'
const resolvers = {
  // Scalars
  Date: DateTimeResolver,

  myModels: async () => {
    return await context.user.getMyModels()
  }
}
```

My query returns `date: "2021-02-07T06:58:51.009Z"`. Is it possible to have Apollo Client convert it to a Date object instead?

Comment: each/all custom scalar must be de-/serialized, search github issues for possible solutions (link, field resolver)

Comment: Yes, I found this library but can't get it working: https://github.com/eturino/apollo-link-scalars/issues/244

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out using [apollo-link-scalars](http://github.com/eturino/apollo-link-scalars):

```js
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
} from '@apollo/client'
import introspectionResult from 'shared/gql/generated.schema.json'
import { buildClientSchema, IntrospectionQuery } from 'graphql'
import { withScalars } from 'apollo-link-scalars'
import { DateTimeResolver } from 'graphql-scalars'

const schema = buildClientSchema(
  (introspectionResult as unknown) as IntrospectionQuery
)

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
  credentials: 'include',
})

const typesMap = {
  DateTime: DateTimeResolver,
}
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  (withScalars({ schema, typesMap }) as unknown) as ApolloLink,
  httpLink,
])

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link,
    // TODO: Save and hydrate from localStorage
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    // Necessary to pass the session cookie to the server on every request
    credentials: 'include',
  })
}
```

I looked at my generated schema and found that the scalar was being called `DateTime` instead of `Date` so I changed the `typeMap` to `DateTime: DateTimeResolver` and it's working.

Comment: This solution requires including the entire schema client-side which exposes data that you might want confidential. I wish there was a better solution!